Created a Python app that uses a system tray widget, but the widget is not created when the app is run as an EXE created by PyInstaller
I built a Python script that maps my mouse buttons to certain keyboard function keys. The script is written to allow the app to run in the background as a system tray widget. Some elements of this simple program aren't written yet, but otherwise, it behaves perfectly as expected when run from the IDE.
However, when I run the EXE I built with PyInstaller, the app window does open and operate as expected, but it does not create a system tray widget.
I tried building a second script that creates a dummy system tray widget that does nothing but quits, but that doesn't appear when run from the PyInstaller-made EXE either. Both scripts work as intended with the exception of creating a system tray widget.
Below is my test app code and spec file. Any assistance would be appreciated.
import os
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSystemTrayIcon, QMenu, QAction

app = QApplication([]) 
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False) 

# Adding an icon 
icon = QIcon(os.path.abspath("mouse_tray_enabled.png"))

# Adding item on the menu bar 
tray = QSystemTrayIcon() 
tray.setIcon(icon) 
tray.setVisible(True) 

# Creating the options 
menu = QMenu() 
option1 = QAction("Option 1") 
option2 = QAction("Option 2") 
menu.addAction(option1) 
menu.addAction(option2) 

# To quit the app 
quit_now = QAction("Quit") 
quit_now.triggered.connect(app.quit) 
menu.addAction(quit_now) 

# Adding options to the System Tray 
tray.setContextMenu(menu) 

def check_tray_widget_exists(tray):
    if tray.isVisible():
        print("System tray widget exists and is visible.")
    else:
        print("System tray widget does not exist or is not visible.")
        
check_tray_widget_exists(tray)

app.exec_()

And my spec file:

a = Analysis(
    ['SystemTrayApp.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('mouse_tray_enabled.png', '.')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='SystemTrayApp',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)```


You need to ensure that resource paths are properly referenced when using "frozen" binaries. The first thing you should do is to check that the path appropriately points to the icon (eg. print(not icon.isNull()). Check this post and do some research for related queries. Also, assuming that you didn't solve the issue based on the hints above, provide proper env info (most importantly the OS and related wm/dm/env if on Linux) and the output of the program when run on a terminal or prompt.

Thanks for responding, @musicamante. Before I share my env info, just one question. Are you pointing to the line in my spec file datas=[('mouse_tray_enabled.png', '.')] and saying that the path to the .png file needs to be ensured?

No, I mean that you cannot just rely on a relative path based on where the "script" is, because they are normally based on the working directory, which is the path from which the program is launched: it could also be a different one even when running the script alone: for instance, if you run python C:/myprog/app.py in the prompt while the prompt is currently in a different directory, it won't work anyway. Using "frozen" binaries also complicates things, as the working dir is that of the exe, not where the prog data is temporarily extracted.

As said, you always have to reconstruct the path based on the actual path of the relative path, considering the relative path used in the script. This is even more important when dealing with bindings like Qt, which have absolutely no idea of the Python aspects or where its scripts currently are while running. The post linked above (as similar ones do) addresses that aspect. In any case, add the line suggested in my first comment, and you'll likely get a False (not icon.isNull() tells whether the icon was loaded or not). Even a basic os.path.exists(path) will tell you the same.

Just to be clear, this isn't a case of the widget icon just not showing up in the system tray. The widget itself doesn't show up. As in, there's nothing clickable created in the system tray, not even a blank space. Is your answer still the same?
Sorry, I'm not trying to be obtuse. It just seems like you're telling me that PyInstaller isn't recognizing the absolute path of the PNG file.

Also, I ran the code print(not icon.isNull()) as you suggested and it returned True.

QSystemTrayIcon is not a widget, it's an API that interacts with the OS in order to show an icon. The fact that the icon is loaded is strange, though. Try following the third solution in this post, it seems there could be some issues with pyinstaller (see this report). Also check isSystemTrayAvailable().

First, I ran the demo and there is a tray widget showing up.


Then, I build the exe using pyinstaller --add-data="icon.png;." main.py, and the system tray widget is still there.


So I assume there is nothing wrong with your code. I would guess that you might not add the mouse_tray_enabled.png successfully when building exe. Please try the command above and see if there is the png file at the same directory of exe.
If that's not the case, please consider changing PyInstaller's version. I'm using:

PyInstaller == 5.12.0
PyQt5 == 5.15.10

By the way, if the QSystemTrayIcon widget doesn't find the icon file. There won't be any tray widget, not even a blank space.

Hi there. I tried what you suggested and still no luck. I'm using PyInstaller 6.9.0 and PyQt5 5.15.9. Should I roll back PyInstaller?

@AgentFoxtrot I think it's worth a try. Install PyInstaller==5.12.0 and see if it works.
